# kendo ui tooltip location

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui for my web design and at the moment i am stuck on the positioning of my validation tooltip. Wierd enough that for any dropdowns it appears exactly where i want it to appear, which is below the input, but for plain text inputs, the validation tooltip appears beside the input element. this is giving my page an inconsistent look. I have searched kendo documentation for tooltip but its not as detailed as i would like it to be and does not offer much help.

Any ideas how can i make sure my validation tooltip, regardless of the element type it is applied on, appears below the field being validated?

See the screenshot for more clarification:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just realised i have not got enough points to post up a picture..so.. not sure how am i able to show you guys the screenshot i have :)

Comment: If you have a link, post it as a comment and I'll edit the question for you

Comment: thanks a lot colin.. what i did is posted up the pic on facebook and here's the link: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150806976165876&l=46f5ad20de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could try something like this.**

I had a lot of trouble because I could add a callback handler to the validate event but it wasnt' called on blur events only on posts and I wanted to have inline to show on a summary at the top in real time.

First disable validateOnBlur so that the default stuff doesn't popup.

```
 var validatable = $("form").kendoValidator( { 
    validateOnBlur:false,
    ...
    });
```

**Next you can add your own validate callback.**

As I noted this doesn't get called on blur.

```
        validateOnBlur:false,
        validate: function (e) {
          ....
        },
```

**Call validate on blur so that the fields are updated on blue.**

Since we disabled this lets make sure it gets called both on form post as well as blur.

```
    $("#input, textarea").on("blur", function (validator) {
        validator.validatable.validate();
    }.bind(null,this));

      // valid on submit where you like
    submit: function () {
        if (this.validatable.validate()) {
            $("#form1").submit();
        }
    },
```

**Summary is easy to do. I put them at the top of my page in a control with a class errors-section**

I copy the errors and put them somewhere else on the page in a summary. I also use some jquery to put a little star before the label. Note the **next()** is the span that has the error text.

```
        validate: function (e) {
            $(".k-invalid").next().each(function () {
                $(".errors-section").append($(this).text()).show();
                $(this).text("");
            });
        },
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the markup and styling of your page. Adding `display: block` to the input fields might solve the problem, or if you are using `float`s, adding a `clear:left` and the necessary `margin` to the validation messages.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I found to this is override the CSS .k-tooltip-validation and place it wherever you want, as the following example:

```
.k-tooltip-validation {
        margin-top: -40px !important; 
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Nice and easy especially for styling within popup grid editor, which is tricky. Thanks.